# Compiling tinygroupdtls

Tags: c, makefile, linker-errors, contiki, dtls

I am trying to compile the tinygroupdtls ([tindygroupdtls](https://github.com/nikirill/tinygroupdtls)) on Contiki 2.7. Currently, I am getting a linker error.

```
LD        multicast-client-example.sky
multicast-client-example.co: In function `secure_group_creation':
multicast-client-example.c:(.text.secure_group_creation+0x6): undefined reference to `dtls_new_group'
multicast-client-example.c:(.text.secure_group_creation+0x5e): undefined reference to `dtls_cipher_new'
multicast-client-example.c:(.text.secure_group_creation+0x6c): undefined reference to `dtls_add_group'
contiki-sky.a(er-coap-13.o): In function `dtls_config_context':
er-coap-13.c:(.text.dtls_config_context+0xa): undefined reference to `dtls_new_context'
contiki-sky.a(er-coap-13.o): In function `coap_send_message':
er-coap-13.c:(.text.coap_send_message+0x48): undefined reference to `dtls_write'
contiki-sky.a(er-coap-13-engi): In function `process_thread_coap_receiver':
er-coap-13-engine.c:(.text.process_thread_coap_receiver+0x1c): undefined reference to `dtls_init'
er-coap-13-engine.c:(.text.process_thread_coap_receiver+0xaa): undefined reference to `dtls_handle_message'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [multicast-client-example.sky] Error 1
Process returned error code 2
rm multicast-client-example.co obj_sky/contiki-sky-main.o
```

I am not sure if the source files in the tinygroupdtls folder are getting compiled, and causing this problem...

Following are my makefiles:

The project makefile

```
all: multicast-client-example server-example


# variable for this Makefile
# configure CoAP implementation (3|7|12|13) (er-coap-07 also supports CoAP draft 08)
WITH_COAP=13
WITH_CONTIKI=1
# variable for Makefile.include
WITH_UIP6=1
# for some platforms
UIP_CONF_IPV6=1
CFLAGS += -DUIP_CONF_IPV6=1


CONTIKI=../..
CFLAGS += -DPROJECT_CONF_H=\"project-conf.h\"


# linker optimizations
SMALL=1

# REST framework, requires WITH_COAP
ifeq ($(WITH_COAP), 13)
${info INFO: compiling with CoAP-13}
CFLAGS += -DWITH_COAP=13
CFLAGS += -DREST=coap_rest_implementation
CFLAGS += -DUIP_CONF_TCP=0
APPS += er-coap-13-mcast-dtls
endif

CFLAGS += -DWITH_COAP=13 -DWITH_CONTIKI=1 -DUIP_CONF_IPV6=1
CFLAGS += -DUIP_CONF_IPV6_RPL=0
CFLAGS += -DNDEBUG=0
#CFLAGS += -DDEBUG=1
CFLAGS += -DWITH_MULTICAST=1
CFLAGS += -DWITH_GROUP_RESPONSE=1

CFLAGS += -DWITH_DTLS=1
APPS += tinygroupdtls/aes tinygroupdtls/sha2 tinygroupdtls

APPS += erbium


include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include
```

The application makefile (Makefile.tinygroupdtls)

```
ifeq ($(WITH_GROUP_RESPONSE), 1)
tinygroupdtls_src = dtls.c crypto.c hmac.c rijndael.c sha2.c ccm.c netq.c dtls_time.c peer.c group.c key_derivation.c
else
tinygroupdtls_src = dtls.c crypto.c hmac.c rijndael.c sha2.c ccm.c netq.c dtls_time.c peer.c group.c
endif
```

Can anyone please tell me what I could be doing wrong here?

Thanks